# Network statistics: reading ifconfig rx drop count

Tags: linux, debian, ethernet, ifconfig, statistics

Need to get the RX drop counter incremented in Linux ethernet interface (`ifconfig` RX dropped: should increment),  for some statistics testing.

I am using 2 virtual PCs, with Ubuntu.

I tried the following things:

1. Disable the Ipv6 on the system and sending Ipv6 packet.
2. High Ping (200 ms)

How else can I increment the RX dropped counter?

Comment: one question: why?

Comment: The question is pertinent. What are you really trying to acomplish and what NIC hardware are you using? Please edit the question to add the data.

Comment: Need to check the rx drop counter for some statistics testing. For now using 2 virtual PCs... with ubuntu. Once I am able to do it in PCs then will do it in specific hardware.

Answer (score 0):

For getting network/interface advanced statistics, VMs without additional hardware/setup are not supposed to work.

It is imperative to use a real machine with real NICs or use a PCI-passthrough configuration of an additional NIC card, and use that hardware exclusively from the VM in question as if it were installed in a real machine (if the virtualisation/hypervisor behind used allows this to be done).

Due to their nature, virtual NICs won't be fit to get statistics of your network health, in varying degrees depending on your VM network design and whether they are bridged or NATed. In the extreme less optimal scenario, you have paravirtualized cards like vmxnet in Vmware VM or even NICs in Xen, where you are doing little more than passing data back and forth, and the actual NIC physical behaviour is not emulated anymore by the hypervisor.

As for the actual cards, depending on the level of details you need to capture, not all cards are born equal. Beware some cheaper models/USB adapters may throw way information/packets on which you are interested, and what goes/is visible to the upper layers is just a subset of the activity of your network. (as an example, cheap cards as a Realtek won't cut it)

I used to do network performance consulting, and at that time, I usually used either a Intel Ether Express pro card or a 3Com NIC of a specific model I cannot remember at the moment.